# UIScrollView ignores constraints

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a ScrollView, which has constraints to surrounding views. So, it should resize its height and width depending on the screen size. And it actually does it in Interface Builder. So, if I change the device in "View as: ..." the height of ScrollView also changes. But... It doesn't work in simulator or in a physical device. If I am trying to run the app in simulator or real device, I get the ScrollView sizes of that device, which is chosen in Interface Builder in "View as: ...".

For example: I choose iPhone SE in "View as: ..." and then run the app on my iPad mini 2. So, I get the ScrollView height which was calculated for iPhone SE, but too small for iPad. And vice versa. So, as I understand, Xcode ignores ScrollView constraints during the runtime.
Any ideas?

Screenshot
[image]

Updated code with constraints
[image]

Screenshot of .xib View
[image]

iPad simulator screenshot
[image]

iPhone 8 simulator screenshot
[image]

Console output 
[image]

Screenshot with All constraints
[image]

Comment: what do you have in the scrollview?

Comment: Please show screenshots of constraints of that scrollview

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: @hardikparmar I have a kind of custom paging view. The content (page) is a .xib file and added programmatically to this scroll view.

Comment: Have you tried adding a subview to the scrollview and then add the custom view in the added subview?

Comment: @hardikparmar just tried. It stopped scrolling.

Comment: but the scrollview size issue was resolved?

Comment: @hardikparmar nope

Comment: try adding "equal width to mainView(superview of scrollview)" and "equal height to superview(scrollview)" constraint to the subview of scrollview @Roman

Comment: @hardikparmar an interesting thing: I removed my content view (pages) and ScrollView resizes correctly now on any device.

Comment: @Roman then the issue is with the content view only. as the scrollview gets its content size from its content only.

Comment: @hardikparmar ok, I see. I'll try to fix it, thanks for help!

Comment: @Roman If you can attach screenshot of that custom view, I can also have a look at it .

Comment: @hardikparmar added the screenshot

Comment: @Roman okay, have you tried adding "equal width to mainView(superview of scrollview)" and "equal height to superview(scrollview)" constraint to the subview of scrollview? cause seems like this custom view will have a fix size in every device. So first try what I suggested before and then revert me back. This should fix the issue.

Comment: @hardikparmar I added some code (marked blue), but it doesn't work. The "AdvantageView" still has fixed size. Maybe it is conflicting with content's height (marked red) or I placed it wrong?

Comment: @Roman set the width equal to superview of the scrollview. you are setting it equal to the scrollview. That's not gonna help. Update me after you try this. Also set the `multiplier` to 1.

Comment: @hardikparmar nothing has changed. The main problem is - it still ignores constraints and sets sizes depending on the device which is chosen in InterfaceBuilder. Look at new screenshot of iPhone 8+ simulator. Gray - is ScrollView, green - XIB View. ScrollView resized well, but XIB still has fixed size.

Comment: @hardikparmar and now I just changed device to iPad in Interface Builder. So it started looking like a s**t (sorry).

Comment: @Roman Do one thing. remove the top constraint of the label which is given to the bottom of the imageview. I hope that will fix this.

Comment: and instead of 254 do scrollview.frame.size.height @Roman

Comment: @hardikparmar now it looks awesome, but still uses the sizes of current device chosen in "View as...", so I have to (for example) at first choose View as: iPhone8+ and then run iPhone8+ simulator. Otherwise it looks awful.

Comment: @hardikparmar I printed some sizes into console and what I get when the app starts: size of AdvantageView is ok and equal to backgroundView, but the ScrollView has a size not of the current device (iPad) but of device chosen in "View as: " (iPhone 8). Take a look at the new screenshot.

Comment: @Roman I need to look at the constraints of the whole screen.

Comment: Also show me the latest screenshots of iPad and iPhone 8.

Comment: @hardikparmar I managed to fix the width. Now it is ok on every device in every orientation. I could do it because I set the width of superview of the ScrollView fixed size - without any constraints. But I can't fix the height in a such way because I can't do without constraints there. Added screenshot with all constraints.